# What does the adverb as modify in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

“The man is as tired as a sloth.”
In this sentence, I know the first “as” modifies tired, but what does the second one modify?

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit more precise, [englishgrammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/asas/) explains:

> The structure ***as…as*** is used to compare things that are of similar proportion.
>
> In this case *the first* **as** acts as an *adverb modifying the adjective or adverb that goes after it*. *The second **as*** can act as a **preposition** or **conjunction**. If it is used *as a preposition, it will be followed by a **noun** or pronoun*. If it is used *as a conjunction, it will be followed by a **clause***.
>
> - He is ***as*** cunning ***as** a fox*. (Here the first *as* in this construction modifies the adjective *cunning*. **The second as modifies the noun fox**.)
> - He drove ***as*** fast ***as** he can*. (Here the first *as* modifies the adverb *fast* and **the second as modifies the clause ‘he can’**.)

However, [Grammarquizzes](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/sameas.html) asserts that the second ***as*** is a preposition whether it is followed by a noun or a clause:

> The comparative ***as…as*** expresses that two items have equivalent aspects. The first ***as*** modifiers the quality (Adj) or manner (Adv) of the item being compared. *The second **as** is a **connective preposition** which is followed by a noun or a clause*. If it is a clause, it is shortened to just the subject and the auxiliary form of the verb.

What is definite is that the second *as* followed by a noun is a preposition. So, to apply this to your example, the second ***as*** is used as a preposition having as a prepositional object the noun *a sloth*.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EL&U, Joe!

The structure **as + adjective/adverb + as** is used to compare things that are similar in some way.

For example:

*She was **as cold as** ice.*
*Your cat is **as big as** a dog.*
*He eats **as quickly as** I do* (or ...*as quickly as me*.)
*I am **as hungry as** you are.*

Your example isn't perfect. Sloths aren't necessarily tired: they just move slowly! But of course everyone would understand what you meant.

[This](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The second *as* is licensed by the first. It's not a question of modification, but rather completing a construction.

This is similar to an object being licensed by a verb at the head of a clause. The object does not modify the verb, but is a complement of it.